# convert from mysql to mysqli problem

Tags: mysqli

I recently changed from using mysql to msqli, since then the CRUD functions have all stopped working properly. Please can someone point me in the right direction. Here is my code. sorry for my bad english.

```
public function create() {
global $database;
$attributes = $this->sanitised_attributes();
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".self::$table_name."(";
$sql .= join(", ", array_keys($attributes));
$sql .= ") VALUES ('";
$sql .= join("', '", array_values($attributes));
$sql .= "')";
if($database->query($sql)) {
$this->id = $database->insert_id();
return true;
} else {    
return false;
}

}
```

---

Here is the class

```
class mysqliDatabase {

private $connection;
public $last_query;
private $magic_quotes_active;
private $real_escape_string_exists;  

    function __construct() {
    $this->open_connection();
    $this->magic_quotes_active = get_magic_quotes_gpc();
    $this->real_escape_string_exists = function_exists("mysqli_real_escape_string");
    }

    public function open_connection(){
    $this->connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!$this->connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
      } else {
    $db_select = mysqli_select_db($this->connection,'*****');
    if (!$db_select) { 
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error());    
    } else { echo "connected";}
    }
     }


    public function close_connection(){
    if(isset($this->connection)) {
    mysqli_close($this->connection);
    unset($this->connection);
  }
 }

    public function query($sql) {
    $this->last_query = $sql;
    $result = mysqli_real_query($this->connection, $sql);
    $this->confirm_query($result);
    return $result;
    }

    public function escape_value($value) {

    if($this->real_escape_string_exists) {
    //undo any magic quote effects so mysqli_real_escape can do the work
    if($this->magic_quotes_active){ $value = stripslashes($value);}
    $value = mysqli_escape_string($this->connection, $value);
    } else {
    //if magic quotes aren't already on then add slashes manually
    if(!$this->magic_quotes_active) { $value = addslashes($value);
    }
    //if magic quotes are active, then the slashes already exist
    }
    return $value;
}

    public function fetch_array($result_set) {
    return mysqli_fetch_array($result_set);
}

    public function num_rows($result_set) { 
    return mysqli_num_rows($result_set);
}

    public function    insert_id() {
    //get the last id inserted over the current db connection
    return mysqli_insert_id($this->connection);
    }

    public function affected_rows() {
    return mysqli_affected_rows($this->connection);
    }

    private function confirm_query($result) {
    if(!$result) {
    $output = "Database query failed " . mysqli_error($this->connection) . "<br
    /><br />";
    $output .= "last SQL query: " . $this->last_query;
    die($output);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in this function, but in the database class. You would need to share that one to be able to get help.